# <g:textField> tag with variable width

Tags: grails

I would like to use `<g:textField>` tag with different width depending on database-field I want to enter. I expanded the width by using

```
input[type=text] {
    width: 300px;
}
```

in main.css. Is there a means to parameterize `<g:textField>` with a width parameter or to generate an individual `<g:textFieldWith>` tag based on `<g:textField>`. If so, where can I find the source of `<g:textField>`?

Comment: I would like to use g:textField tag with different width depending on database-field I want to enter. I expanded the width by using

input[type=text] {
    width: 300px;
}
in main.css. Is there a means to parameterize g:textField tag with a width parameter or to generate an individual tag based on g:textField tag . If so, where can I find the source of g:textField tag?

Peter

Comment: what's wrong with `<g:textField name="a" style="width:300px">` or `<g:textField name="a" class="wide">`?

Comment: nothing is wrong with the style attribute, it is working fine and is solving my problem completely. But unfortunately it is not included in the tag documentation of textField. It only includes the name and value attributes. By the way, are there more hidden magic and undocumented attributes ? And where to find their description?

Comment: You can apply any HTML attribute to any grails tag. What other "magic" do you need?

Comment: that kind of magic will do, thanks a lot